# Percorre arrays com datas e comparar com a data atual

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso criar um método que compare em dois ou mais arrays se a data atual é maior que as datas de vencimento (date_paymentX) que existem nesses arrays e retorne quantas ocorrências existem.

Método:

```
public function payments()
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); // Retorna 2017-08-09

    $services = Service::all()->toArray();

    dd($services);

}
```

O dd() exibe:

```
array:2 [▼

0 => array:22 [▼
"id" => 1
"date" => "2017-08-09"
"date_payment1" => "2017-08-01"
"price1" => "500"
"payment1" => "Não"
"date_payment2" => "2017-08-15"
"price2" => "500"
"payment2" => "Não"
"date_payment3" => "2017-08-20"
"price3" => "500"
"payment3" => "Não"
"customer_id" => 1
"created_at" => "2017-08-09 10:52:12"
"updated_at" => "2017-08-09 12:28:31"
]

1 => array:22 [▼
"id" => 2
"date" => "2017-08-09"
"date_payment1" => "2017-08-01"
"price1" => "500"
"payment1" => "Não"
"date_payment2" => "2017-08-15"
"price2" => "500"
"payment2" => "Não"
"date_payment3" => "2017-08-15"
"price3" => "500"
"payment3" => "Não"
"customer_id" => 1
"created_at" => "2017-08-09 12:09:56"
"updated_at" => "2017-08-09 12:29:12"
]

]
```

Nesse exemplo existem 2 pagamentos vencidos. Precisaria que o método retornasse esse valor(2).

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta. Melhor que a minha para falar a verdade. Você pode responder sua propria pergunta. E na minha opiniao a sua está mais performatica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples assim...

Comentei no código para que você entenda e possa modificar se necessitar.

```
public function payments()
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); // Retorna 2017-08-09

    $services = Service::all()->toArray();

    $contagemDeVencimentos = 0; // quantidade de pagamentos vencidos

    for($x = 0; $x < count($services); $x++){

        foreach($services[$x] as $key => $dataPagamento ){

            // faz uma pesquisa e verifica se a chave atual tem esse inicio (date_payment)
            if(strstr($key, "date_payment")){
                // se a data do pagamento for menor que a data de comparação (hoje)...
                if(strtotime($dataPagamento) < strtotime($date)){
                    $contagemDeVencimentos++; // adiciona mais uma quantidade
                }
            }

        }

    }

    echo $contagemDeVencimentos; // mostra a quantidade final
}
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Conforme novas informações indicadas nos comentários

```
public function payments()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d'); // Retorna 2017-08-09

        $services = Service::all()->toArray();

        $contagemDeVencimentos = 0; // quantidade de pagamentos vencidos

        for($x = 0; $x < count($services); $x++){

            $number = 0;
            foreach($services[$x] as $key => $info ){

                if(strstr($key, "date_payment")){
                    if(strtotime($info) < strtotime($date)){
                        $numberPayment = explode("date_payment", $key);
                        $number = $numberPayment[1];
                    }
                }

                if($key == "payment".$number){
                    $number = 0;
                    if($info == "Não")
                    $contagemDeVencimentos++;
                } 

            }

        }

        echo $contagemDeVencimentos; // mostra a quantidade
    }
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado.

Comment: Esqueci de um detalhe, mesmo que a data estiver vencida mas tiver um "Sim" em algum dos paymentX, não entre na contagem.

Comment: @Marcelo tranquilo. Farei a ediçao logo mais.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma que acabei fazendo para resolver o problema se o pagamento foi feito ou não:

```
public static function payments()
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $services = Service::all()->toArray();
    $overdue = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($services); $i++){
        $overdue = 0;
        foreach($services as $service) {
            for($n = 1; $n <= 3; $n++) {
                if(strtotime($date) > strtotime($service['date_payment'.$n]) && $service['payment'.$n] == "Não" ) {
                    $overdue++;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    return $overdue;
}
```

Comment: Otimo script. Parabéns.